# Проблема создания PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: java, база-данных, веб-программирование, исключения, connection-pool

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

У меня проблема создания PoolableConnectionFactory.
Все сделал как было показано в уроке, файлы context.xml and web.xml подстроил под свою базу данных.
При вызове БЗ в тестах, все работает. Значит БЗ существует.
у меня есть подозрения что это

```
ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/CityRegister");
```

Скорее всего я не правильно указываю адрес, но та информация которую я нашел в интернете, говорит что путь указан правильно. Есть еще вариант с файлом web.xml
что я мог там что-то сделать...

Comment: `FATAL: database "CityRegister" does not exist`  схема в БД с учетом регистра совпадает? Какая база данных используется? Может у пользователя под которым подключаетесь нет прав на CityRegister?